# How to put values for 2d array using their index

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to initialize a 2-dimensional array by accessing its index values. Whenever `x < y` (for ex `dp[0][1]`), then it should be `0`, and if `x==y`, then it should be `1`.

```
dp =Array.new(max+1,Array.new(3,0))
print dp
dp.each_index do |x|
  dp[x].each_index do |y|
    if x==y then
      dp[x][y] = 1
    elsif x<y then
      dp[x][y] =0
    end
  end
end
print dp
```

Before the loop initializes, all the values of the array are `0`. But after the loop executes, all values become `1`. When I do `dp[x].insert(y,0)` instead of `dp[x][y]`, the loop runs forever. Please help me on solving this issue.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Santhosh if index x &y are same then dp[x][y] = 1 and if x<y dp[x][y] =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
dp = Array.new(3){Array.new(3)}
print dp
dp.each_index do |x|
  dp[x].each_index do |y|
    if x==y then
      dp[x][y] = 1
    elsif x < y then
      dp[x][y] = 0
    end
  end
end
```

**output is:**

```
[[1, 0, 0], [nil, 1, 0], [nil, nil, 1]]
```

**Note:** this is a rough idea you can update it as you want or can ask me to update.

**Update Explanation:**

```
a = Array.new(2,Hash.new)
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"},{"cat"=>"feline"}]
a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"},{"cat"=>"Felix"}]

a = Array.new(2){Hash.new}    #**Multiple instances**
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # =>[{"cat"=>"feline"},{}]
```

Comment: Hey thanks @G.B . Works like charm :) By the way can u please explain the difference b/w dp =Array.new(max+1,Array.new(3,0)) and dp = Array.new(3){Array.new(3)}

Comment: see the edit. actually the difference is your method uses 1 instance while mine method uses multiple instances of subarray